# Is it possible to have type hints in a separate folder within the same project?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, type-annotation

I'm adding type annotations to a package I maintain. According to PEP484 stub files for type annotation (`.pyi`) can either be distributed alongside the actual code [in the same directory](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#storing-and-distributing-stub-files) or in a third-party package. Having the `.pyi` files in the same directory, however, seems inelegant and I would much prefer to have them separated; similar to how this is done for headers and implementations in C/C++.

In a nutshell, my current package structure is something like this:

```
my_project
|   setup.py
|   pyproject.toml
|   ...
|
|___my_package
|   |   __init__.py
|   |___module_1
|   |   |   __init.py
|   |   |   fancy_module.py
|   |   |   fancy_module.pyi
|   |   |   ...
|   |
|   |___module_2
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |   more_files.py
|   |   |   more_files.pyi
|   |   |   ...
```

and I would like it to be something like this (with type annotations supported by mypy and vscode at least):

```
my_project
|   setup.py
|   pyproject.toml
|   ...
|
|___my_package
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   |___module_1
|   |   |   __init.py
|   |   |   fancy_module.py
|   |   |   ...
|   |
|   |___module_2
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |   more_files.py
|   |   |   ...
|
|___stubs
|   |___module1
|   |   |   fancy_module.pyi
|   |   |   ...
|   |
|   |___module2
|   |   |   more_files.pyi
|   |   |   ...
```

Is this possible or do I need to look into distributing a separate "third-party" package?

Comment: "Having the .pyi files in the same directory, however, seems inelegant" I'd argue not really on that one.. it's a very common convention for Python. If it's a library you also maintain, why not add types directly to the `.py` files and skip stubs altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes you can do this, just create a "stubs" directory at the root level of your project and place the `.pyi` files inside it! if you want to sure that `mypy` and other tools recognize these separate stub files, you can configure them to include the "stubs" directory in their search paths!

but if you prefer third-party package,first of all create a new package for the stub files,for example `my_package-stubs`, then organize the stub files in the third-party package based on the structure of your main package, something like this :

```
my_package-stubs
|___my_package
|   |___module_1
|   |   |   fancy_module.pyi
|   |   |   ...
|   |
|   |___module_2
|   |   |   more_files.pyi
|   |   |   ...
```

now, include `my_package-stubs` as a dependency in your main package's `pyproject.toml` or`setup.py`, and by doing this, when users install your main package,the stub files from the third-party package will be installed alongside it.

**pyproject.toml**

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "my_package-stubs",
    ...
]
```

**setup.py**

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'my_package-stubs',
        ...
    ],
    ...
)
```

Comment: No need to add stub packages as core dependencies of the project as they only are required by static analyzers, not used during a typical runtime. Use project "extras" to make it an optional dependency.